# After doing a count with groupby, I want to plot by the groupby variable

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I did a value count with a groupby, here is the code. All_data4 is a dataframe.

```
typecount = all_data4.groupby("Index_Date")['UPLOAD_TYPE'].value_counts()
```

Typecount looks like the following. How can I plot with X axis being the date, and plot two bar charts grouped by the UPLOAD_TYPE for each date?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please post your data as *code* that we can copy-paste instead of screenshots. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for how to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from you point...
First, you could reset your index:

```
typecount.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Then, split new index column into 2 columns:

```
new_df =pd.DataFrame(typecount["index"].to_list(), columns=['Index_Date', 'UPLOAD_TYPE'])
```

Then you can plot your data in stacked mode:

```
  # importing package
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      
    # plot bars in stack manner
    plt.bar(new_df['Index_Date'], new_df[new_df['UPLOAD_TYPE']=='Actual'], color='r')
    plt.bar(new_df['Index_Date'] , new_df[new_df['UPLOAD_TYPE']=='Pro'] , color='b')
    plt.show()
```